# html table : is it possible to style inexistant cells or must I add them to the code?

Tags: html, css, html-table

#### context :

I work on a little csv-like script editor,
and I use an html table to display the data

[image]

As you can see there are missing cells.

That was to be expected, since I only insert the cells containing data
(and the previous cells of the row),
and the border style is only applied on cell elements for now.

I'd like All the cells to be displayed,
and I wondered if it was possible to draw the table lines
without cells, or if the only solution is to insert the missing cells ?

#### minimum reproducible example :

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>B2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>C3</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 2px solid #555;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid #888;
}
</style>
```

Comment: to style an element it obvisoly need to exist. Why not use CSS-Grid?

Comment: @tacoshy except for pseudo-elements

Comment: Why don't you use colspan?

Comment: @D.Schaller Pseudo-elements do actually exist. They just added through css and not directly in the HTML markup. Non-existing elements do not exist at all.

Comment: @tacoshy tomato tomato. depends on the interpretation of exists in this context, I guess. 
They don't exist in the HTML as an element, yet they are able to be styled. And whenever they are styled, they come to existence.

Comment: @D.Schaller there no interpretation. Like I said. Pseudo-element do exist as they added through CSS therefor they also can be styled. Try to style a non-existing element and make them come to existance that way... It is just complete BS.

Comment: I though for a moment I could try something with a pseudo element `td::after` that would draw a line with full width/height of the table between each cell, but that's not the way this works... thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we know elements who do now exist will not shown you have to add  as needed to your table with no data in it. and you can set your code like below.

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 2px solid #555;
    empty-cells: show;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid #888;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>B2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>C3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `empty-cells: show;` was a good hint, but 1) it only works when `border-collapse: separate;` and 2) it doesn't  make inexistent cells visible, just empty `<td></td>` ...

Comment: But you are right, seems like the only thing to do is to add these missing cells, thank you